# Opengl light direction

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to set up a simple directional light in opengl. My scene init code:

```
float light_position[] = { 0, -1,0, 0.0f };
float light_ambient[] = {1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
float light_diffuse[] = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };

float mat_ambient[] = { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
float mat_diffuse[] = { 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };

glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, light_ambient);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, light_diffuse);

glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
```

Then I render just one triangle:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();

glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, light_position);
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT, mat_ambient);
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE, mat_diffuse);


glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glNormal3f(0,1,0);
    glVertex3f(0,-1,-2.0f);
    glNormal3f(0,1,0);
    glVertex3f(-1,-1,-1);
    glNormal3f(0,1,0);
    glVertex3f(1,-1,-1);
glEnd();
```

I except that the light is like the sun, shining from up to down (towards -infinity on y axis), so my triangle should be yellow (red ambient material + green diffuse), but my triangle is red, like if there aren't any light. If I change the light position to {0, 1, 0, 0}, then the triangle become yellow. Why? The light direction is from the position set to (0,0,0)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The interpretation is the opposite. A light position of `{ 0, -1,0, 0.0f, 0.0f }` defines a light in the downwards direction, shining upwards. Therefore, this light does not illumniate your triangle, while a light at `{ 0, 1,0, 0.0f, 0.0f }` does.

Comment: So the light always shining towards (0,0,0), from it's position?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Unless you specify another direction (e.g. for spot lights)

Comment: No, a light shines everywhere from its position.

Comment: @PeterJames Not a directional light. It does not have a definite position.